# ASP.NET Chart control doesn't render with DatabindXY

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am trying to make a line chart where I have a list of integers for one series and a list of dates for another series. I have a chart control on my aspx page that looks like this:

```
<asp:Chart ID="chtBurnHistory" runat="server">
    </asp:Chart>
```

I have the following codebehind which passes in a list of integers and a list of dates to the DatabindXY() method:

```
    string curSeries = "series1";
    chtBurnHistory.Series.Add(curSeries);
    chtBurnHistory.Series[curSeries].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    chtBurnHistory.Series[curSeries].Points.DataBindXY(burnValueLists[0], burnDateLists[0]);
    chtBurnHistory.Series[curSeries].Color = Color.Red;
    chtBurnHistory.ImageType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageType.Jpeg;
    chtBurnHistory.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("burnHistory"));
```

The values of 'burnValueLists' and 'burnDateLists' are lists of both lists of integers and datetimes respectively.

The problem I am having with this chart is that it never renders. I have this method in a button click event and when I click the button the chart never changes, it just displays the default no chart image. Am I doing something wrong or is there another step to allow the chart to render?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial it really good it should help you get what you are doing correctly .
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx

I think you also need series in the control

```
<asp:Chart ID="chtBurnHistory" runat="server">
 <Series> 
      <asp:Series Name="series1" ChartType="Column" ChartArea="MainChartArea"> 
      </asp:Series> 
   </Series> 
   <ChartAreas> 
      <asp:ChartArea Name="burnHistory"> 
      </asp:ChartArea> 
   </ChartAreas> 
    </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: I took a look at the link and noticed that initially I was not setting my chart area. So I went back and it set it appropriately but still have the same issue. Just the placeholder image and no chart =/